# Use regular expression in XSD element name

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

I'm trying to implement a XSD for my XML code.

```
    </transition>
    <!--The list of automata-->
    <Machine0/>
    <Machine1/>
    <Machine2/>
    <Machine3/>
  </automaton>
</structure>
```

The problem is with the `Machine[i]`, the number of `Machine[i]` elements changes in each XML file.

I've tried with this code, but doesn't seem to work:

```
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:assertion test="every $x in * 
     satisfies matches(local-name($x), 'Machine[0-9]+')"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Horrible design.  Why are you encoding the position of a machine as part of its name?  Is the consuming code too feeble to be able to keep a running count?  What you should do is not solve the problem but push back against the design.

Comment: I know is a bad design, the code that i show is a part of the xml code, and is not my design, i needed to create a xsd for that xml code, but i solved it!

Answer (score 1):

First, a few notes:

1. **Most importantly**, if you still have design control over the naming of the `Machine` elements, do realize that you ought to have a very good reason for straying from the superior design pattern where element position is implied rather than represented explicitly in an element's name.  I like `xs:assert`, so I don't like anyone giving the XSD WG members [*reasons to regret its inclusion in XSD 1.1*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919939/use-regular-expression-in-xsd-element-name/36920451?noredirect=1#comment61408512_36920451).  **;-)**
2. It's `xs:assert`, not `xs:assertion` (common typo).
3. You'll want to anchor the start and end of your regex.  (Unlike with `xs:pattern`, `fn:matches()` does not automatically anchor the start and end of its pattern.
4. You'll need `processContents="lax"` or `="skip"` unless you intend to define `MachineN` elements explicitly.

---

### XSD 1.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    vc:minVersion="1.1">

    <xs:element name="r" type="rType"/>

    <xs:complexType name="rType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:assert test="every $x in * satisfies 
                         matches(local-name($x), '^Machine[0-9]+$')"/>
    </xs:complexType> 
</xs:schema>
```

Then, this XML

**Valid case #0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<r>
    <Machine0/>
    <Machine1/>
</r>
```

will be ***valid*** per your XSD, but these XML documents,

**Invalid case #1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<r>
    <xMachine0/>
    <Machine1/>
</r>
```

**Invalid case #2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<r>
    <Machine0x/>
    <Machine1/>
</r>
```

**Invalid case #3**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<r>
    <Machine/>
    <Machine1/>
</r>
```

will be ***invalid***, as requested.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but im pretty new working with xsd and xml, and your code gives me an error:

Not valid.
Error - Line 35, 40: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 35; columnNumber: 40; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'rType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
Error - Line 36, 34: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 36; columnNumber: 34; s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'sequence' must match (annotation?, (element | group | choice | sequence | any)*). A problem was found starting at: complexType.

Comment: The XML and XSD I've provided are correct and have been verified.  The errors you mention obviously do not correspond to the XSD I've provided as they're listed on lines 35 and 36, and my answer XSD has half as many lines.  You've made mistakes updating your real XSD based on the shortened example I've provided.  Start with checking for a `@targetNamespace` and updating the `@ref` accordingly.  If you're still having trouble, post a new question as tracking this down in comments won't work well.

Comment: Also make sure you're using a XSD **1.1** capable processor.  I hope I've helped you with the essence of your question regarding assertions on element names via regular expressions.

Comment: An impressive answer to a wrong-headed question.  (This is precisely why some WG members were reluctant to accept assertions in XSD 1.1 -- it makes so many poor designs easier to build.)

Comment: Added **note #1** to address @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen's basic design consideration I was remiss to have not mentioned originally.  Thanks!